# Snapshot of Achievement Levels by Date

Tags: excel-formula

[Expected Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPwIn.jpg)  [Expected Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja5mv.jpg)1.    I have a spreadsheet with a list of dates when student signed-up for lessons (Column A). Note: Sometimes multiple students sign up on the same day.
2.  The sheet also contains the dates when the students attained certain Proficiency levels (Columns B through F).
3.  I would like to know retroactively (on any given sign-up date) how many students I had at each of the various proficiency levels.
4.  If they have not yet achieved a Level of Proficiency I do not wish to include them in my categorical proficiency level counting.

So, in my example/link above, my output for the Sign-up date of 11/7/1996, should be that I had: (1) Student at Level 6 (3) Students at Level 3 (2) Students at Level 4. Would anyone have some ideas how to achieve this?

What I have started is the following in Column "I" and then dragging down. However I am not getting accurate counts (the accurate counts in columns "I" through "M" in my attachment link). If I could achieve accurate counts w/my present formula, I could use a similar formula in columns J,K,L and M etc. =COUNTIFS($B$2:B8,"<="&A8,$C$2:C8,">"&A8)+(COUNTIFS($B$2:B8,"<="&A8,$C$2:C8,"<>")))

Comment: it makes it much easier for people to help you when you include the example data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Historical Student Attainment levels by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71029338/historical-student-attainment-levels-by-date)

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you. No,  I am still having trouble with the formula that I created above. I'm getting the wrong output (my numbers do not match my expected output in my image-attached. BTW, can you see my image attached on this post...I can, but Prema said an example (which is what my image contains) would be helpful?

Comment: I mean data so the helpers can copy it to excel and then work with it. It is to much work to type the dates on your picture

Comment: Okay, thank you for explaining Prema...and that makes sense. I will do that later this afternoon.

Comment: Hi Prema, would be able to let me know what your preferred way is to see an example of someone's spreadsheet. I looked at Table, but it renders my spreadsheet unreadable. For example what is the most common form that people use for displaying an example in my situation. I am completely new to this process. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I have to leave this. I wrote all the data to Excel, but finnaly I realised that I don't understand which dates to count. Sorry. I leave it.